# Passing Value between non related components

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want a value to be passed from Tabs component to Task component, I created a separate data service. The value in Tabs is obtained as a parameter from other component. On trying to obtain to pass the value  from Tabs to Task component, it  gives me 'undefined' in Task Page.

My Service class

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';  

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

   list:any;

   getUserData(){ 
      return this.list; 
   } 
   setUserData(data:any){
       this.list = data;
   }
}
```

Tabs Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SettingsPage } from '../settings/settings';
import { TasksPage } from '../tasks/tasks';
import { DataService } from "../../services/data.service";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
  providers:[DataService]
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = TasksPage;
  tab2Root = SettingsPage;
  user:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public dataService: DataService) {

  this.user = navParams.get('param1');    
  this.dataService.setUserData(this.user);
  }
}
```

Task Page

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../../services/data.service";
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';
import { TasksCreatePage } from '../tasks-create/tasks-create';

const logger = new Logger('Tasks');

@Component({
  selector: 'page-tasks',
  templateUrl: 'tasks.html',
  providers:[DataService]
})
export class TasksPage {
usern:any;

constructor(public dataService: DataService){
this.usern = this.dataService.getUserData();
console.log(this.usern);
}
```

Comment: By using `providers:[DataService]` you telling angular to create seperate instance of `DataService` instead of using singleton.

Comment: Thanks , resolved my issue .

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `navParams.get()` is an asynchronous function.
Replace this:

```
this.user = navParams.get('param1').then( () => {
    this.dataService.setUserData(this.user);
});
```

to this:

```
this.user = navParams.get('param1');    
this.dataService.setUserData(this.user);
```

Comment: Yes, Instead of using singleton , I tried to create separate instance of DataService.
Thanks.